# I can't add subViews in UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying add a subview to UIScrollView. I add scrollView, subView and set constraints bellow :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let scrollView : UIScrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    return scrollView
}()

let catImageView : UIImageView = {
    let img = UIImageView()
    img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    img.backgroundColor = .white
    return img
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .black

    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.frame = self.view.bounds
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 1000)

    scrollView.addSubview(catImageView)
    catImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    catImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    catImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    catImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
 }
```

I builded and scrollView and subiew are disappear. I don't know why...
Then I trying add subview another way like this :

```
        view.addSubview(catImageView)
    catImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    catImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    catImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    catImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

It's still the same. Please explained to me why. Thank a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` in case you are adding the constraints to the view. You've set the property on the `scrollView` to `false`, but used the `frame`, and not constraints. Remove the line:

```
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // <- remove
```

and it should work.

Hope this helps! Good luck!